# Best way to get the value from a tuple in C#

Tags: c#, .net, tuples

Below is my code

```
public Tuple<string, string> GetMultipleValue()
{
    frmKbCPT mFrmKbCpt = new frmKbCPT();
    mFrmKbCpt.MaximizeBox = false;
    mFrmKbCpt.Height = 600;
    mFrmKbCpt.Width = 800;

    mFrmKbCpt.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    mFrmKbCpt.ShowDialog();
    string cptrate = mFrmKbCpt.txtRate.Text;
    string mStr = mFrmKbCpt.txtCode.Text;
    mFrmKbCpt.Dispose();

    return Tuple.Create(cptrate, mStr);
}
```

In the button if I want to populate the two textboxes I do this

```
Tuple<string, string> getvalue = new Tuple<string, string>(GetMultipleValue().Item1, GetMultipleValue().Item2);

txtCPT1.Text = getvalue.Item1;
txtCpt1Prate_opdamt.Text = getvalue.Item2;
```

My problem is that it show my form  frmKbCPT twice. Is there a way to get the tuple item2 without repeating again the function GetMultipleValue()? Thanks and more power!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call it once:

```
Tuple<string, string> getvalue = GetMultipleValue();
```

Since you're calling it twice, it will do its job twice.

So call it once.

Comment: Thanks @wudzik for catching that I forgot the variable name, but I decided to edit in the variable name the OP used in his question.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to call the function once, save that return value in a variable, and use that variable to fill you textboxes. That way the function is only called once, thus executed only once.

```
Tuple<string, string> temp = GetMultipleValue();

txtCPT1.Text = temp.Item1;
txtCpt1Prate_opdamt.Text = temp.Item2;
```